# Rails 3 UJS unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I have such a form:

```
<form id="new-application" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-remote="true" action="/inv/claims?locale=uk" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are You sure?" href="/inv/claims/1?locale=uk">delete</a> 
<a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are You sure?" href="/inv/claims/2?locale=uk">delete</a> 
</form>
```

Also I have in my.js such lines of code:

```
var toggleLoading = function() { $("#ajax-loader").toggle() };

$("#new-application")
    .bind("ajax:loading",  alert('loading'))
    .bind("ajax:complete", alert('complete'))
    .bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      alert('succ');
    });
```

When I click on **delete** I only get a message **succ** but I am waiting for a message **loading** and after that a message **succ**.

**Why Doesn't I get a message loading before succ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://tesoriere.com/2011/05/19/rails-3.1-—-fixing-the-%27ajax-loading%27-event/).

Hope it helps.

Here is the URL:

```
http://tesoriere.com/2011/05/19/rails-3.1-%26%238212%3B-fixing-the-'ajax-loading'-event/
```